# "mdwlist.sty" file not found

Tags: packages

I am new to latex, whenever I quick build my latex document it shows an error ("`mdwlist.sty`" file not found). I googled it many times but I am not getting anything, please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What TeX distribution are you using? Can you make a small example of a document producing the error?

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the `mdwtools` bundle. But you should know it is superseded by tthe  `enumitem` package that allows for complete customisation of lists.